# Problem with setInterval when i LIMIT mysql rows

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, chat

I've made simple chat with setInterval that will load everything from `if($q == "load") {`, and everything works fine but when i want to limit rows from db, for example i want my chat to show only last five, i change this line:

`$load = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id > $data");`

to this

`$load = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id > $data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");`

The setLimiter goes crazy and starts to add every second 5rows + 5rows + 5...etc and they are not the same, it just adds 5 on top every second even when i limit it.

I want to make it to show only last five rows and thats it. I know its simple but looks like ive made mistake somewhere.

**EDIT:**

This is where i am so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/hg6m32ys/1/

Now when i type message, it goes on top (showing oldest first) until i refresh page, then they go from newest. And limiter is working only on refresh, before that it will display more then 5 messages.

Here you can check demo: https://www.zlatniglas.rs/chat.php

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question. See [mcve]

Comment: your JS load every second `setInterval(load_chat, 1000);` you have to stop via JS and not via SQL LIMIT, if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: @daniel i dont wanna stop it, it is doing his job until i set limit for rows, then it starts loading those i limited and on top of that the rest every second.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you set `curr_id = retr.id;`
Then on the next api call you send the new id which will have a different response.

You should set

```js
data: {q:"load", data:0}
```

In your `load_chat` function.

And also empty your chat if you don't want to append the same messages multiple time with:

```js
$("#chat-ul").empty();
```

Before calling the first `print_msg` in your `load_chat` function.

The final function could be like this:

```js
function load_chat() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/chat.php",
        data: {q:"load", data:0},
        success: function(retr){
            var msgs = retr.data;
            for(msg in msgs) {
                print_msg(msgs[msg]);
            }
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }).fail(function () {
        print_msg("error: chat can't be loaded!");
    });
}
```

If you don't want to empty your message to refresh them, you could check if the message already exists in the message list and add it only if it doesn't exist.

```js
function print_msg(msg) {
    var output = "";
    const exists = document.querySelectorAll("#chat-ul .id_" + msg['id']).length !==0;
    if (exists) return;
    if(msg["text"].length === 0) return;
        output = "<span class=id_" + msg['id'] +"><img src='../images/avatars/" + msg['avatar'] + "' width='35' height='35' class='rounded-circle'>" + msg["username"] + ": " + msg["text"] + "</span><br>";
    $("#chat-ul").prepend(output);
    var length = document.querySelectorAll("#chat-ul>span").length;
    while (length >5) {
        $('#chat-ul>span:last').hide(); 
        length--;
    }
    
    $("#chat-ul").scrollTop($("#chat-ul")[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

Comment: Now its duplicating row id 0 (first message).

Comment: You copied the exact function I wrote and it does that? Does it duplicate only the first message or the first 5 messages?

Comment: Its working now but now i get again the problem when i highlight the message with mouse, it resets after 1 sec.

Comment: That was because to refresh the messages, we emptied the list each time. I edited my answer to change that. Copy the new load_chat function and print_msg function and tell me if it works.

Comment: Now i dont get messages in chat.

Comment: I edited the print_msg function, now I tested it, it should work.

Comment: Wow you are so good at this. Everything is working fine. Just one more think i found bugged out. When i type messages it is DESC like it needs to be, but when i refresh the chat they go ASC.

Comment: You want new messages on the bottom or on the top?

Comment: on bottom...now when i type the go from bottom, but when i refresh the page they go from top.

Comment: I changed the print message function, tell me if it is how you want it.

Comment: Now they got added on top and are not limited by 5 like i set.

Comment: `$load = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id > $data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");`

Comment: Change the print message function again. Is it fixed now?

Comment: Now when i remove all messages and type first 5 they go on top and after 5 they dont update, after i refresh the page they go to bottom (correct way).

Comment: My bad, I edited print_msg again ^^

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have `$('#chat-ul>span:last').hide();` in your code? with **last** and not first

Comment: yeah, i would like you to record video so you can see how it behave. idk

Comment: I don't know sorry, for me it works but but I don't have all your code so I don't know what's going wrong for you :/

Comment: [link](https://zlatniglas.rs/chat.php) i uploaded to host, if you can check